# How to "echo" a variable from a Javascript function into html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the function below to rotate images on click into the `#home-image` div, beginning with the first image.

Javascript:

```
$('#home-image').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'img1_on.jpg') src = 'img2_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img2_on.jpg') src = 'img3_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img3_on.jpg') src = 'img4_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img4_on.jpg') src = 'img1_on.jpg';
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

HTML:

`<img id="home-image" src="img1_on.jpg" />`

**But**

I want to "echo" the file name of the image being displayed, so the viewer sees the name of the image.

How would I "echo" the name of the image into another div, i.e. `<div id="home-image-name"></div>`?

This is an attempt to echo the output of `src` into the `home-image-name` div, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#home-image').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'img1_on.jpg') src = 'img2_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img2_on.jpg') src = 'img3_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img3_on.jpg') src = 'img4_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img4_on.jpg') src = 'img1_on.jpg';
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    var output = 'src';
    document.getElementById("#home-image-name").innerHTML = output;
    }
});
```

**This works, with the additional window.onload functions to show the image name on page load:**

```
 window.onload = function(){
    $("#home-image-name").html($('#home-image').attr("src"))

$('#home-image').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'img1_on.jpg') src = 'img2_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img2_on.jpg') src = 'img3_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img3_on.jpg') src = 'img4_on.jpg';
        if (origsrc == 'img4_on.jpg') src = 'img1_on.jpg';
        $(this).attr('src', src); 
        var output = 'src';
      document.getElementById("home-image-name").innerHTML = src;
}
});
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("#home-image-name").innerHTML = src;`

Comment: @j08691 no need to tag this [jquery]. Not all JS questions containing jquery need the tag. Especially when the answer doesn't involve any jquery at all.

Comment: @PeeHaa - True, however it is relevant as omitting it would imply a pure JavaScript answer was required. And a jQuery solution, like `$("#home-image-name").html(src)` would be viable.

Comment: @juvian - Don't you mean `getElementById("home-image-name")` (no `#`)?

Comment: @PeeHaa - How do you know that it is? Plus with the OP's rep of 1, I'm assuming that he simply omitted it.

Comment: @j08691 true, just noticed the other mistake

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if this needs to be jQuery.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch - Is a jQuery answer acceptable?

Comment: I changed the function to document.getElementById("#home-image-name").innerHTML = src; with no luck.

Comment: Sure, jQuery is fine; I just need to duplicate the current image click rotation function.

Comment: It's funny how this is getting voted to close

Comment: its `document.getElementById("home-image-name") `... no `#` .. If something does not work out of the box, try to understand why, instead of just trying the next solution. Come on, there is no need for jQuery on this question. Please do not take a JS newcomer and turn them into jQuery fanatics before they understand js

Comment: Why the downvotes and close votes?

Comment: And dont rotate by replacing the image, you can actually rotate it with CSS

Comment: @juvian among others, you're right, no # needed, and I just realized the html will appear after the first click. So does someone want to enter that as an answer?

Comment: @j08691 this now works without the need for jQuery, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I said + @j08691 comment, the correct sintax would be:

```
document.getElementById("home-image-name").innerHTML = src;
```

As the `getElementById` method takes a string of the id, with no need of #. And output was just a string, so you could either change `output = src` which is kind of redundant, or just put src.

Jquery way:

```
$("#home-image-name").html(src)
```

If you want to also do it on page load before click:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("#home-image-name").html($('#home-image').attr("src"))
}
```

Comment: Cool, the window.onload is what I need. But, stupid question, I get an "Expected token '}'" error with: `... $(this).attr('src', src); } window.onload = function(){ $("#home-image-name").html($('#home-image').attr("src"))  }  });`

Comment: @BlueDogRanch the window.onload function should be outside the .on scope, just below <script> tag

Comment: Hmmm...  that shows the first image title, but doesn't change on click, i.e.: `<script>window.onload = function(){
    $("#home-image-name").html($('#home-image').attr("src"))
}
$('#home-image')...`

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I´m not sure about your full code but should be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/swgbamdL/

Comment: Cool! Works fine. Blimey, this stuff gets complicated, very quickly :)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch well, could always read documentation on window.onload and other stuff. And can always ask another question here, plenty of people willing to help

Comment: Thanks, I'm obviously a (and somewhat an obliviously) beginner....

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, a simple:

```
$('#home-image').click(function(){
    $('#home-image-name').html(this.src.split('/').pop())
})
```

should work.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/66otfe35/)**

Also if you wanted to use this code with several images, you could use the following (which uses a common class):

```
$('.home-image').click(function(){
    $('#home-image-name').html(this.src.split('/').pop())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oj32kcst/)**

Comment: Interesting, your first answer works fine, but only displays the image name after the first click.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Ah, getting ahead of myself with juvian's answer....

Answer (score -1):

remove the `#` from

```
document.getElementById("#home-image-name").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: copy-paste from the comments above..and it's wrong..

Comment: Needs to be document.getElementById("home-image-name").innerHTML = src;

Comment: @RonniSkansing No, copy paste from the OP question, and how is it wrong?